# Identifier must be declared with a port mode: busy. (Verilog)

Tags: verilog

I have the Verilog code shown below, and when I compile it, I get the following error message and the first line of the code is highlighted:

**Error:**

> Identifier must be declared with a port mode: busy.

**Code:**

```
module main(clk, rst, start, busy, ready, cnt, s, a);

input clk, rst;
input [3:0] start, s, a, cnt_A;

output ready;
output [3:0] cnt;

wire busy, ready;
wire [3:0] cnt;

assign start[0] = s[0] & a[0];
assign start[1] = s[1] & a[1];
assign start[2] = s[2] & a[2];
assign start[3] = s[3] & a[3];
//assign cnt_A = 4'd12;

counter ucounter(.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .start(start), .busy(busy), .ready(ready), .cnt_A(cnt_A), .cnt(cnt));

always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (!rst) begin
        start <= 4'b0000;
        s <= 4'b1000;
        a <= 4'b0010;
    end
    else if (!busy) begin
        s <= s >>> 1;
    end
    else if (ready) begin
        a <= a >>> 3;
    end
end

assign cnt = cnt;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cnt_A` is listed as an input put not in the port list.

```
module main(clk, rst, start, busy, ready, cnt, s, a); // <-- No cnt_A
// ...
input [3:0] start, s, a, cnt_A; // <- cnt_A here
```

---

As Tim pointed out busy is in the port list but not declared as an input or output.

Also the assignments to `start` will not work. You cannot assign an input.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not the problem. It says that there is problem with the variable named "busy".

Comment: @ett, updated and you will have another error with assigning `start`.

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. I defined it as an input, but now I have 5 errors with the message: Illegal reference to net, at the assignments inside the always. What I want to do if reset comes to give the default value to those inputs, and there is not busy or there is ready, I want to shift the 1 bit in those variables (of s and a).

Comment: @ett: You **can't** assign anything to input signal.

Answer (score 0):

`busy` is in the port list, but it is not listed as an input or output in your module.